# recursive type become any after emit declaration, need implicit solution

Tags: typescript

I am creating a npm package, basically it is a function that return an object that return the return of the function itself

```
export const chainCreator = () => {
    return {
        chain: () => {
            return chainCreator()
        },
        end: () => {
            return 'end'
        },
    }
}
```

[image]

so far so great, the type is ok

but thing break when I build it:
[image]

it returns `any` type instead, so this is a big no

There is a solution, by typing it explicitly (type annotations)

```
type chainCreator = {
    (): { chain: () => ReturnType<chainCreator>; end: () => string }
}
export const chainCreator: chainCreator = () => {
    return {
        chain: () => {
            return chainCreator()
        },
        end: () => {
            return 'end'
        },
    }
}
```

[image]
This works as expected, however, I prefer an implicit solution(type inference), because it is more automated, less maintenance is needed and more accurate.

this is my config

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "esNext",
        "allowJs": true,
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "paths": {
            "*": ["*"]
        },
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

so my question is, is there any implicit solution for recursive function like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, TypeScript doesn't currently have a way to emit a reasonable [declaration file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) for an *anonymous* recursive type.  There's a very old open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#463](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/463) discussing this problem, and while there have been some improvements over `any` in IntelliSense (you get those ellipses `...` when things are too long), the type emitted to declaration files is still just `any`.

There's a suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#44045](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44045) to support generating automatic [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) in declaration files to give a name to anonymous types that are hard to expand either because they are very large or recursive and therefore infinite.  It's not clear when or if something like this will be implemented.  It wouldn't hurt to give that issue a  but it probably wouldn't help much either.

Until and unless something changes, you should just give anonymous recursive types an explicit name like `ChainCreator` and use that, if you need to generate accurate declaration files.